# Laravel permissions : The super-admin bypass on auth provider doesn't work

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-permission

I'm using spatie's laravel-permission package and created roles and permissions on my application and wrote a bypass for the super-admin role, as specified on their doc, in the AuthServiceProvider. It worked like a charm, and suddenly it stopped working for no apparent reason, returning a 403 error. I already rebooted the server and cleared routes cache. I can't find the reason why this stopped working...

Here are my AuthServiceProvider and routes

AuthServiceProvider :

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    // allows super-admin everywhere in the app
    Gate::before(function (User $user) {
        return $user->hasRole('super-admin') ? true : null;
    });
}
```

Routes:

```
// admin only management
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:writer']], function () {

    //admin dashboard
    Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.dashboard');

    // blog management
    Route::get('articles', [AdminArticles::class, 'index'])->name('admin.articles.index');
    Route::get('articles/create', [AdminArticles::class, 'create'])->name('admin.articles.create');
    Route::get('articles/my-articles', [AdminArticles::class, 'myArticles'])->name('admin.articles.myArticles');
    Route::get('articles/{article}/edit', [AdminArticles::class, 'edit'])->name('admin.articles.edit');
    Route::get('articles/{article}/delete', [AdminArticles::class, 'destroy'])->name('admin.articles.destroy');
    Route::put('articles/{article}', [AdminArticles::class, 'update'])->name('admin.articles.update');
    Route::post('articles', [AdminArticles::class, 'store'])->name('admin.articles.store');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:super-admin']], function() {
    //pages
    Route::get('/homepage', [HomepageController::class, 'create'])->name('admin.home.create');
    Route::get('/homepage/{homepage}/edit', [HomepageController::class, 'edit'])->name('admin.home.edit');
    Route::put('/homepage/{homepage}', [HomepageController::class, 'update'])->name('admin.home.update');
    Route::post('/homepage', [HomepageController::class, 'store'])->name('admin.home.store');

    //users
    Route::get('users', [UsersController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');
    Route::get('users/json', [UsersController::class, 'usersJson'])->name('users.json');
    Route::get('users/create', [UsersController::class, 'create'])->name('users.create');
    Route::get('users/{user}/delete', [UsersController::class, 'destroy'])->name('users.destroy');
    Route::get('users/{user}/edit', [UsersController::class, 'edit'])->name('users.edit');
    Route::put('users/{user}', [UsersController::class, 'update'])->name('users.update');
    Route::post('users', [UsersController::class, 'store'])->name('users.store');
});
```

Comment: are you getting error? you said that it stopped working but what happens when you try to access any route which requires superadmin role? please explain it. otherwise I would prefer to remove Gate method from AuthServiceProvider and make your own middleware that checks user's role and if the role is superadmin only then he can access the routes

Comment: When I access a route with super-admin role I get to it as usual, but when I access a route with writer role I get a 403 error, not authorized. Maybe I should make a middleware indeed, but it's too bad, the Gate should work... I could also just add super-admin access in each of my routes, but this loses the concept of the bypass and the role needs to be specified as any other role.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? I am having the same issue though mine happened after I refactored my code and change the models' namespaces

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Gate only checks if you are giving permissions through "permissions" not through "roles" as is your case.

What I mean is that if you were using:

```
// admin only management
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['permission:write']], function () {
```

instead of

```
// admin only management
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:writer']], function () {
```

It would work.